# proof - any positive integer can be uniquely expressed as $a = 3^m + 3^{m-1}b_{m-1} + \cdots + 3^0b^0$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, induction

I had been trying to prove that any positive integer can be uniquely expressed as $$a = 3^m + 3^{m-1}b_{m-1} + \cdots + 3^0b^0 \text{ where each b = -1, 0 or 1 and } a \in \mathbb{Z}^+$$
This is a problem from Niven's Introduction to Theory of Numbers.

**My Attempt:**

Proof by Strong Induction.

Let $P(n) ::= n = 3^m + 3^{m-1}b_{m-1} + \cdots + 3^0b^0 \text{ where each b = -1, 0 or 1 }$.

Base Case: P(1) is true. Since $1 = 3^0$.

Assuming $P(1), P(2), \cdots, P(n-1)$ is true to prove it for $n$.

Considering cases:

Case 1: $n = 3m$
$$\implies n = 3(3^m + 3^{m-1}b_{m-1} + \cdots + 3^0b_0)$$
$$\implies n = 3^{m+1} + 3^{m}b_{m-1} + \cdots + 3^1b_0 + 3_0*0$$

Case 2: $n = 3m+1$
$$\implies n = 3(3^m + 3^{m-1}b_{m-1} + \cdots + 3^0b_0) + 1$$
$$\implies n = 3^{m+1} + 3^{m}b_{m-1} + \cdots + 3^1b_0 + 3_0*1$$

Case 3: $n = 3m-1$
$$\implies n = 3(3^m + 3^{m-1}b_{m-1} + \cdots + 3^0b_0) - 1$$
$$\implies n = 3^{m+1} + 3^{m}b_{m-1} + \cdots + 3^1b_0 + 3^0*(-1)$$

This is how I've managed to prove the above proposition(I am not sure though). **Is my proof correct? Please report even the slightest mistake.** Also, how can I prove that they are unique.

Could you prove the above proposition in some other way without using induction and by using number theory because I feel I haven't used it? I believe there must be other techniques of proving this by using some number theory concepts.

Thanks.

My question includes proof verification alongwith other questions and it is hence not a duplicate.

Comment: What you are actually trying to prove is that any positive integer can be uniquely expressed in base 3. Though it wouldn't consitute a 'proof' unless made rigorous, you could think of an intuitive argument such as taking away powers of 3 from the original number repeatedly.

Comment: Some comments. First you're using $m$ for two different purposes which is somehow confusing. Second you proved the existence but not the unicity.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes, you're right. I wanted a proof that also proves that they are unique.

Comment: @shardulc This is not about the standard expression in base $3$ as each "$3$-git" is in $\{-1,0,+1\}$ not in $\{0,+1,+2\}$

Comment: @shardulc This problem has been known since ancient times. This is its mathematical representation.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Sorry, didn't read the problem carefully, but the intuitive idea can still be used.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I feel that proving its uniqueness is easy intuitively. How can a simple equation of positive numbers of positive powers have two results.

Comment: @Dhruv OK... then you should be able to write down a proper proof.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net That's the problem. I don't know how to begin.

Comment: First prove that $m$ is uniquely defined. And then prove that the $b_i$ are also uniquely defined. For that notice that $- \frac{3^m-1}{2} \le 3^{m-1}b_{m-1} + \cdots + 3^0b_0 \le \frac{3^m-1}{2}$

Comment: The fact that the "digits" are $0,\pm1$ instead of $0,1,2$ makes this into the so-called _balanced_ ternary system. Early computers were some times made to work in this system rather than binary.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263649/proving-that-a-nonzero-integer-n-has-a-unique-representation?rq=1.