# Simple induction. Do I have to use it three times for each value?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have the following problem, $n = e_{k}3^k + \ldots + e_{1}3 + e_0$.

With $k\geq0$, where $e_i \in \{1,0,-1\}$ for all $i \in \{0, \ldots,k\}$

And I have to prove that every natural can be represented that way, with Simple Induction. Do I have to do simple induction three times, each one for a different $e_i$?

Edit:

I got stuck in all of the paths. This is what I have:

- For $e_i=0$: $P(0)=0$, $P(n)=0$, so $P(n+1)=1$ which is natural. (I don't know if this is right).
- For $e_i=-1$: $P(0)=0$, $P(n)=-3^k-...-3-1$, so:   $P(n+1)=-1(3^k+...+3)$. (I think in this case I cannot assume that this number is natural).
- For $e_i=1$: $P(0)=0$, $P(n)=3^k+...+3+1$ so:
  $P(n+1)=3^k+...+3+1+1$

In summary, I don't know what I am doing. I am new at this.

Comment: What are you trying to prove? You need to tell us the desired conclusion.

Comment: The inductive step is easy unless $e_0=1$.  Do you know what to do in that case?

Comment: You are misinterpreting the condition. Saying that $ e_i \in \{ 1, 0, -1\}$ doesn't mean that $e_ 0 = e_ 1 = e_2 = \ldots$.  It could be that (say) $e_0 = 0, e_1 = -1, e _2 = 1$, which gives $ 0 + (-1)\times 3 + (1) \times 3^2 = 6$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving that a nonzero integer n has a unique representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263649/proving-that-a-nonzero-integer-n-has-a-unique-representation) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24n%3De_%7Bk%7D3%5Ek%2B%5Cldots%2Be_%7B1%7D3%2Be_0%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24e_i%5Cin%5C%7B1%2C0%2C-1%5C%7D%24&p=1). There are also other duplicates, e.g., [Prove that each nonzero integer may be uniquely represented in the form](/q/2259526), ...

Comment: (cont.) [How to decompose number into sum of powers of 3 with coefficients from set {-1,0,1} (is my algorithm correct)](/q/3845958), etc., as well as AoPS threads, e.g., [Number Theory](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1828563p12238468). Last, but by no means least, welcome to Math SE.

Comment: Before you try to prove anything related to this, you should spend some time understanding what it is that you're trying to prove.  In order to do that, you should consider a bunch of small values of $n$ (I don't know, maybe all single-digit positive integers) and figure out what the theorem says about each of them.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Every natural number is either a multiple of $3$ or one more or less than a multiple of $3$.  For the induction step, if $x = 3^k e_k + \ldots + e_0$, what are $3x-1$, $3x$ and $3x+1$?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to see that it holds for $n=1$. Suppose the result holds true for $m\leq n$. So $m=a_k3^k+\ldots +a_13+a_0$, for some $a_i$’s in $\{-1,0,1\}$. Now
$$\begin{align}
    m+1 &= (a_k3^k+a_{k-1}3^{k-1}\cdots + a_13+a_0)+1 \\
    &=a_k3^k+(a_{k-1}3^{k-1}\cdots + a_13+a_0+1) \\
    &=a_k3^k+(e_{k}’3^{k}\cdots + e_1’3+e_0’)
\end{align}$$
Where the last line inside the brackets comes from the fact that the bracketed part is at most $m$ ($a_k$ cannot be negative, else $m+1$ would be). If $e_k’\neq 1$ then we are done; otherwise $(a_k+e_k’)3^k=2\cdot3^k=(3-1)3^k=3^{k+1}-3^k$. In this case
$$m+1 = e_{k+1}3^{k+1}+e_k3^k+\cdots + e_13+e_0$$
With $e_{k+1}=1$, $e_k=-1$, and $e_i=e_i’$ for every other $i$.